# Avoid an Error Message when Importing

Tags: import, warning-messages, variable-definitions, save, error-trapping

Consider the following code

```
Button["Import", file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]; 
 data = Import[file], Method -> "Queued"]
```

which yields a button which, upon clicking, opens a directory window from which I can access my files and import one. However, in Windows 10, if I click "Cancel", that is,

[image]

I get back the following message, regarding `$Canceled`,

[image]

How do I avoid such a message? That is, if I click "Cancel" I want both `file` and `data` to remain non attributed.

I thought about simply checking whether `data` or `file` are `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`, but not sure how to do this or if there is a better way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new and this is my 1st answer. Try the following:

```
Button["Import", file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]; 
If[ Not@TrueQ[file == $Canceled], data = Import[file]], 
Method -> "Queued"]
```

Comment: That works, thank you!!